# Disable DispatcherTimer while a phone call is active on WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

My WP7 (silverlight) app keeps getting rejected because it "should not continue vibrating in the case of an incoming phone call". However, just reacting on the `Applicaton_Deactivated` event does not allow me to fix the problem since this method is not called on an incoming phone call...

The problematic vibration is done through a `DispatcherTimer`, which keeps running in the background behind a phone call. Moving the execution to the main thread didn't change anything.

Do apps just continue running normally behind phone calls? Or is there any way to stop the vibration?

**Initialization of vibrator and timer:**

```
vibrator = VibrateController.Default;
vibratorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
vibratorTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(vibrateRepatedly);
vibratorTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, UIConstants.VIBRATION_INTERVAL);
vibrationSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, UIConstants.VIBRATION_DURATION);
```

**Tick method:**

```
private void vibrateRepatedly(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vibrator.Start(vibrationSpan);
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code you are using to run the vibration using a dispatch timer?

Comment: Ok, added the code for the DispatcherTimer and vibration. Btw, when `Application_Deactivated` is called, I do a `vibratorTimer.Stop()`, which works with locking the device, but not with phone calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**During an incoming call** the `Obscured event` is called and not `Application_Deactivated event`.
You will get an Obscured event in the app, but you can't distinguish if this due to an incoming call, an incoming SMS or reminder.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is a link to the MSDN documentation of the Obscured event you get. There is a corresponding `Unobscured event` you can also detect.

Comment: Usage: `(Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Obscured += MyObscuredHandler;`.